# MongoDB: Find an element in an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a simple array in my MongoDB collection:

```
"_id": "5669b4930874f8d01f7676da", "cars": ["BMW", "Audi", "VW"]
```

I now want to check if "Audi" is in that document. I've read through all questions on arrays here at SO but they focus all on array with objects inside, which isn't the case here.

```
db.collectionName.find({ cars: {$eq: "Audi"} })
```

doesn't work (it returns no document).

EDIT: It was my own stupidity, see my comment below on the best solution. So the above query was **always** working. Well, as they say the problem always sits in front of the keyboard ;-)

Neither does:

```
db.collectionName.find({ $elemMatch: { cars: "Audi" }})
```

It actually leads to the following error message:

```
error: {
"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue unknown top level operator: $elemMatch",
"code" : 17287
```

or:

```
db.collectionName.find({ cars: { $in: "Audi" }})
```

This leads to the following error:

```
error: {
"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $in needs an array",
"code" : 17287
```

Tested with MongoDB version 2.6.7 via MongoDB shell. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simplify:

```
db.collectionName.find({ cars: "Audi" })
```

Should work perfectly.

```
db.collectionName.find({ cars: { $in: ["Audi"] }})
```

Could work too, but first is simpler.

Comment: It was my problem being stupid. I actually created this cars example but in my collection I used I was (to use the same example here) searching for "Ford" and that's obviously not in the array, hence I got 0 docs back. Thanks, did spend another 30 minutes trying to figure out why yours was working and mine not.

Answer (score 0):

this query  seemed to work for me:

```
 db.cars.find({cars: {$elemMatch:{$eq:"BMW"}} })
```

result

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5669ca2ff0fbefa0650e5fb6"), "cars" : [ "Audi","BMW", "Honda" ] }
```